# ExternalStorage does not create files in release version

Tags: android, performance

The problem is that when developing in the debug version, everything is in order, I can easily write files to memory. But I'm making a release version for Google Play, and the logs show that it simply cannot create a folder / file.
I dug up all the documentation, all the permissions are as written, but apparently I still missed something. Tell me, help

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:minSdkVersion="30"
        tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />

 android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

Comment: Are you positive that the app have the MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE granted? You can check that using https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#isExternalStorageManager()

Comment: What type of your app? Is google play approved your app on Google play? this is for confirmation.

Comment: I am sure that the application is granted MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: Application type personalization. Google play approved